# String comparison (structured text) in bash

Tags: bash, awk, comparison, compare, diff

I need to compare two files (new.txt and old.txt) with a following structure:

```
 <Field1>,<Field2>,<Field3>,<Field4>,<Field5>,<Field6>
```

1. The common lines **must** be skipped.
2. Similar line from new.txt and old.txt should be grouped. I suppose
   that line from old.txt is similar to line from new.txt if
   Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 are the same.
3. Other unique lines should be printed below **grouped by file name**

**So the end task is to make visual comparison easier.**

**Added part:**
Example.

```
$ cat old.txt 
 one,two,three,four,five,six
 un,deux,trois,quatre,cinq,six
 eins, zwei, drei, vier, fünf, sechs
$ cat new.txt 
 one,two,three,four,FIVE,SIX
 un,deux,trois,quatre,cinq,six
 en,två,tre,fyra,fem,sex

$cat comparison_result:
# lines are grouped. So it it easy to find the difference without scrolling.
old.txt> one,two,three,four,five,six
new.txt> one,two,three,four,FIVE,SIX
# end of task 2. There are no more simillar lines.
#
#start task 3.
#Printing all the rest unique lines of old.txt 
echo "the rest unique line in old.txt"
eins, zwei, drei, vier, fünf, sechs
.... 
#Printing all the rest unique lines of new.txt
echo "the rest unique line in new.txt"
en,två,tre,fyra,fem,sex
```

**This can be step 1: skipping common lines.**

```
 # This is only in old.txt
 comm -2 -3 <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt) > uniq_old

 # This is only in new.txt
 comm -1 -3 <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt) > uniq_new
```

I wrote step 1 and this sorted diff as a temporary solution:

```
 # additional sort improves a bit diffs results.
 diff <(sort uniq_old) <(sort uniq_new)
```

It's working, but not ideal.
I refused to use diff, because it starts to compare blocks, missing common lines.

Is there a better way to satisfy 3 demands written above?

I think that it can be done by

1. some improvements to this sort, diff and comm commands (adding sed/tr  to temporary "hide" last two filed and compare the rest).
2. awk

I suppose that awk can do it better?

Comment: Are the files sorted in any particular way? I think I would 1) `comm -3` to eliminate all lines that occur in both files, 2) `sort` the remainder (to get your #2 group next to each other), 3) use `awk` to differentiate between the #2 lines and #3 lines (by comparing fields 1-4 on each line with the values from the previous line, and doing something different based on that comparison - your above `comm` commands are sufficient for the #3 lines).

Comment: What if a line in `new.txt` is identical to one line in `old.txt`, but similar to a different line?  Is the line skipped, or grouped?

Comment: Also, what the heck are you doing?  This sounds like it might very well be an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @ghoti What if a line in new.txt is identical to one line in old.txt, but similar to a different line? It is skipped.

Comment: So probably, it is better to compare uniq_old and uniq_new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{old[$0];next} $0 in old{delete old[$0];next} 1 END{for(line in old) print line}' old.txt <(sort -u new.txt) | sort
```

Let's break it down into parts.

- `-F,` tells awk to use a `,` as a field separator.
- `NR==FNR{old[$0];next}` - In cases where NR (record/line number) matches the line number in the current file (that is, while we're reading the *first* input file), stores the whole line as the index of an associative array, then jumps to the next record.
- `$0 in old{delete old[$0];next}` - Now we're reading the *second* file.  If the current line is in the array, delete if from the array and move on.  This address condition #1 in your question.
- `1` - short hand in awk for "print the line".  This addresses part of condition #3 in your question by printing unique lines from the second file.
- `END{...}` - this loop prints everything that wasn't deleted from the array.  This addresses the other part of condition #3 by printing unique lines from the first file.
- `<(sort -u new.txt)` - uniques the input of new.txt.  If you know that new.txt is unique already, you can remove this bash dependency.
- `| sort` sorts the output, "grouping" things per condition #2 in your question.

Sample output:

```
 $ cat old.txt 
 one,two,three,four,five,six
 un,deux,trois,quatre,cinq,six
 $ cat new.txt 
 one,two,three,four,FIVE,SIX
 un,deux,trois,quatre,cinq,six
 en,två,tre,fyra,fem,sex
 $ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{old[$0];next} $0 in old{delete old[$0];next} 1 END{for(line in old) print line}' old.txt new.txt | sort
 en,två,tre,fyra,fem,sex
 one,two,three,four,FIVE,SIX
 one,two,three,four,five,six
 $
```

Note that the line in french was duplicated, thus dropped.  Everything else was printed, with the two English lines "grouped" by sorting.

Note also that this solution suffers on very large files because all of old.txt gets loaded into memory as an array.  An alternative that might work for you would be this:

```
 $ sort old.txt new.txt | awk '$0==last{last="";next} last{print last} {last=$0} END{print last}' | sort
 en,tva,tre,fyra,fem,sex
 one,two,three,four,FIVE,SIX
 one,two,three,four,five,six
 $
```

The idea here is that you simply take ALL input data from your files, sort it, then use the awk script to skip repeated lines, and print all else.  Then sort the output.  This works on a stream, as far as awk is concerned, but be warned that for very large input, your `sort` command still needs to load data into memory and/or temp files.

Also, as-is, this second solution fails if a particular line is repeated more than once.  That is, if it exists once in old.txt and twice in new.txt.  You need to unique your input files, or adapt the script for that situation.

Comment: Looks perfect! Thank you for such a detailed answer. I'm going to test it right now.

Comment: Your awk expression works good! (I added new line before END to avoid error alert) Currently it doesn't do exactly, what I need. I should edit the question to be more precise. The end task was to make visual file comparison easier. I'll try to fix it myself.